# Show Comment Form on its own Page or Popup

Tags: 8, theming, comments

I am trying to figgure out how to show the comment form on its own page. So far I have been able to show it on a seperate page. All I had to do was to go to field comment setting and uncheck "Show reply form on the same page as comments"

So this allow the comments to show on a new page. The only issue is that the new page still shows body above. Is there any way to hide the body on the comment form page? [image]

Ideally I would like to load the comment form on a popup or modal. Can this be done with bootstrap modal or Colorbox inline?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://agaric.coop/blog/display-forms-modal-dialog-drupal-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using an extra node template for the page where the comment form is displayed:

In your theme file create an extra template suggestion for the comment form:

```
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    $route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();

    if($route_name === 'comment.reply') {
        $suggestions[] = 'node__commentform';
    }
}
```

Create an extra node template `node--commentform.html.twig`, and remove just about everything. You probably want to leave the node title, but otherwise there's nothing you need there:

```
<article{{ attributes }}>

  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
</article>
```

The comment form is rendered outside this template, so you don't need any of it.